# Enable/Disable input by radio selection with jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms

A form with radio buttons. If "Existing" is checked, the "existingnumber" input will be enabled. It works fine during the selection process but does not work onload. On load the input "existingnumber" remains disabled even though it's "checked". This is problematic when the form is submitted, and fails error validation. I've tried appending .change() at the end, and creating a function which I called on document ready but that didn't work. I think I'm missing something. Perhaps I need to get the value first? I'm a bit of a jquery noob.

```
<input type="radio" name="officephone" value="New" id="officephonenew" >
<label for="officephonenew">New</label><br>

<input type="radio" name="officephone" value="Existing" id="officephoneexisting" checked>
<label for="officephoneexisting">Existing</label><br>

<input type="text" name="existingnumber" placeholder="555-555-1234" /><br>

<input type="radio" name="officephone" value="No" id="officephoneno">
<label for="officephoneno">Not required</label>
```

```
$('input:radio[name="officephone"]').change(function(){
    $('input[name="existingnumber"]').prop("disabled",true);
    if($(this).attr('value') == 'Existing') {
        $('input[name="existingnumber"]').prop("disabled", false);
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Cormang/sd8xaj9h/10/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this work on load simply use `filter()` to retrieve the checked radio button and `trigger()` the `change` event on it.

Also note that you can simplify the logic by providing the boolean output of the condition to the `disabled` property and by using `val()`.

```js
$('input:radio[name="officephone"]').change(function() {
  $('input[name="existingnumber"]').prop("disabled", $(this).val() != 'Existing');
}).filter(':checked').trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="officephone" value="New" id="officephonenew" />
<label for="officephonenew">New</label><br />

<input type="radio" name="officephone" value="Existing" id="officephoneexisting" checked />
<label for="officephoneexisting">Existing</label><br />
<input type="text" name="existingnumber" placeholder="555-555-1234" disabled /><br />

<input type="radio" name="officephone" value="No" id="officephoneno" />
<label for="officephoneno">Not required</label>
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you! https://jsfiddle.net/Cormang/sd8xaj9h/15/